# Add a contact to an organization through "profile" public form

Tags: profile, organization

For now our public subscription form is handled by a "profile" that create/modify a contact.

I want to add the organization which the contact belongs to but I don't know how to it ?
Is it possible to have a public list the subscriber can have access to ?

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question, and mention what CMS you are using and what version of CiviCRM? It will improve the quality of your answers!

Comment: down vote
favorite
For now our public subscription form is handled by a "profile" that create/modify a contact. I want to add the organization which the contact belongs to but I don't know how to it ? Is it possible to have a public list the subscriber can have access to ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that in pure CiviCRM all you can do is add the Current Employer field to the profile, which is then a text only field.

If you want that field to be an autocomplete then I think you should try the [Public Autocomplete of Organisation Names](https://civicrm.org/extensions/public-autocomplete-of-organisation-names) extension. There is also a blog written about it [here](https://civicrm.org/blog/allenshaw/more-control-for-current-employer-fields-in-public-forms)